# App Store review and validating social access tokens on server side

Tags: ios-appstore, developer-program

According to [**App Store Review Guideline 5.1.1(v)**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#5.1.1v):

> An app may not store credentials or tokens to social networks **off of the device** and may only use such credentials or tokens to directly connect to the social network **from the app itself** while the app is in use.

Is it gonna be a violation of the above guideline (or any other), if we send an access token from mobile to the backend just for verification purposes?

We want to allow the users to link their social accounts to quicker sign in/up to the app.
The user identity can only be validated on the server side given a valid access token, otherwise, anyone can send any random email or account ID and impersonate any other user.

Most social networks limit the access token to the IP address where it was issued.
Is this justification enough? Or is it a grey zone? (it'd be ridiculous) 
If it's not enough, we can only declare but we obviously can't guarantee that we are not going to *use* the access tokens off of the device, because we *send* them to our backend.

Answer (score 0):

Only Apple can really determine if something is a violation of your agreement with them.

However, given the scenario you describe, it sounds reasonable that this would be allowed, and not flagged by the App Store review team as a validation.

Note that I base this on the fact that you write that logins to the social network happens from the app itself on device, that the tokens are not stored on y our server, that your servers does not attempt to communicate with the social network and that the token is only used for verifying that the user has indeed successfully logged in.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! Yes, definitely only Apple can close the question completely, so this answer is more about the industry experience. Because despite the case must be absolutely legit, it looks like violating the guideline: "sending" a token to the backend looks like "using the token off of the device" to me. It's sad that the guideline wording is so misleading.

Comment: Answering the note: we are not going to use the token on the server side, because we obviously can't (it's limited to the user's mobile device IP address), but the whole question is about "is there an appropriate justification for Apple to allow sending the tokens off of the device"? Or is it allowed by default and then we can be banned if we try to communicate with the social network from the backend side? Sorry for so many additional questions — it's kinda important and we'd like to close the question completely if possible.

Comment: I checked a few apps from the AppStore on my personal device, sniffed the requests they send to their backends and some of them actually do send the tokens off of the device, and still are available in the AppStore. Not sure if it's a proof though.